Is it reasonable to believe that God wants us to smoke marijuana?

There are receptors in our brain that respond only to cannabinoids, nothing else. It's called the endocannabinoid system.

Nature makes cannabinoids in only two places: mammal brains and marijuana plants.


From the National Library of Medicine:

These effects reveal the importance of the endocannabinoid system in regulating anxiety-dependent behavior. Results suggest that glutamatergic cannabinoid receptors are not only responsible for mediating aggression, but produce an anxiolytic [anxiety reducing] function. Excessive excitation produces anxiety that limited the mice from exploring both animate and inanimate objects.

In other words, marijuana mellows you out and makes you want to explore your world instead of hiding from it.
It seems to me that all you have to add to this recipe is to believe that  God exists -- not uncommon in philosophy. This doesn't require a Christian-like mythology or a personal god. Personally, I believe that complexity implies intelligent design.
Even if you're a strict Darwinist, you must concede that it's a stretch to believe that this one plant prevents itself from being eaten by making the animals so high that they will wander away and leave the plant alone. But it that's the only alternative you're left with.
Right?

I'm much more inclined to downvote or vote-to-close questions when they feature persecution complexes about the question being downvoted or closed.

Marijuana is a domesticated plant, which humans have been selectively breeding for desirable properties, such as psychoactivity, since 10000 BC. Yes, there was a designer for the modern marijuana plant, and it was humans. The original wild marijuana from 10000 BC was likely not significantly psychoactive because it was initially used for hemp production rather than getting high.

"please believe that I believe this, and I don't want to believe things that are unreasonable. So I'd like to know what other smart people think" so why ask here, the place where you think everyineelse is dumb?"But aren't those the very things that philosophers want to think about" 1. No they don't. 2. We are not philosophers. 3. We also don't find click bait worth thinking.

"And God said, “See, I have given you every herb that yields seed which is on the face of all the earth, and every tree whose fruit yields seed; to you it shall be for food." Genesis 1:29.

"Nature makes cannabinoids in only two places: mammal brains and marijuana plants". Did you smoke all other plants to check they have no cannabinoids? And where else should nature make cannabinoids? In rocks? Clouds? Volcanoes?

@tkruse Early civilizations did that, according to ethnobiology. There are very few plants in the United States that haven't been smoked. This appears to be the only one that God provided for that purpose. === University tesearchers have repeatedly gone into the distant jungles to smoke plants that don't occur in the US. === where else should nature make cannabinoids? In rocks? === No, not in rocks. I've always strongly believed that there's no such thing as a stupid question, but this really pushes it. === Where does your anger come from? I have no idea, and it frightens me.

Calmness and discovery through marijuana: Mental experiences induced by substances are phenomenological and subjective. However, tying the discovery of truth to a chemical alteration is not a strong argument, as reason and experience are the primary tools of knowledge, not altered states.
Complexity and intelligent design: The argument from design is an old philosophical claim, but Darwinian evolution provides a sufficient explanation for complexity. The need for a designer is a metaphysical presumption without empirical evidence.
The role of the plant in survival: Adaptation is a natural feature explained by natural selection. There is no necessity to infer intentionality or purpose in nature.
Opposition votes: Disagreement with an idea should be based on reasoning, not bias. However, for an idea to be valid, it must be grounded in coherent principles and rational illumination, not merely personal belief.

Premise 2 is false.

Cannabinoids are several structural classes of compounds found in the
cannabis plant primarily and most animal organisms (although insects
lack such receptors) or as synthetic compounds. [...]
[P]hytocannabinoids can be found in other plants such as rhododendron,
licorice and liverwort, [and] Echinacea.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabinoid

Frame challenge: it's not reasonable to believe that God exists.

Even if you're a strict Darwinist, you must concede that it's a stretch to believe that this one plant prevents itself from being eaten by making the animals so high that they will wander away and leave the plant alone. But it that's the only alternative you're left with.

I'd describe myself as someone who accepts evolution as the best explanation for the available evidence, and who accepts the consensus of experts, rather than as a "Darwinist" (strict or otherwise). But anyway.
As mentioned in the comments, we have very much been selectively breeding cannabis for at least a while now, to enhance the effects or select for certain traits. Humans have selectively bred all sorts of things, e.g. dogs (which originally evolved from wolves) and cows, and medicine is full of seeing something in nature and refining that to make it more effective (even if that usually happens in a lab in the modern day).
But also, that's an overly narrow view of evolution. Some effects are side effects of otherwise beneficial traits, some detrimental effects stick around because of where a species evolved from. Determining why and how an effect came about is more complex than trying to figure out how it's beneficial.
Like, for example, one might explain a tendency to believe in gods by the beneficial trait of wanting to find explanations, ideally simple ones, for things, and an aversion to attributing things to randomness or meaninglessness (if our ancient ancestors heard rustling leaves nearby, they'd survive more often if they think wolf, rather than thinking "nah, it's probably nothing", or coming up with some highly convoluted explanation for why the leaves rustle).

Then humans were faced with things for which we have no explanation, like "why is there anything".
And we were faced with highly complex things, like billions of years of countless species all going through distinct but interrelated evolutions across a massive planet.
And we were faced with events that happen arbitrary, like some bad things that happen.
And we were faced with not particularly meaningful events, like seeing or hearing a voice or face that isn't there.

And then some people thought up an explanation, to make it sound less complex (on the surface, at least), to make it not arbitrary, and to make it meaningful.

There may be a principle that God wants His creatures to be free, and so would not impose any of His preferences upon them.

Note that the term used for getting high, on any chemical, is intoxication.
For the most part, these chemicals are either waste products toxic to the very cells that created them, or were selected for because they are toxic or distasteful to creatures that might consume those plants or animals. Nicotine, for example, is an insecticide. Alcohol is a waste product. Capsaicin discourages most animals from eating peppers, except birds and humans.
Humans, being relatively large animals with relatively versatile liver enzymes to detoxify chemicals, are able to survive moderate amounts of poison. Indeed, it so happens that we enjoy the effects of some kinds of mild poisoning.
This may have been selected for to allow us to take advantage of more food sources. After all, there are a fair number of animals which will eat fermented fruit; it's easy to smell from a distance, and it still has high caloric content despite the side effects. Specific example: every year, the apple growing regions of the Hudson valley have to deal with raccoons eating windfall apples, getting drunk, and staggering out onto highways. Those which survive have a clear reproductive advantage because they were able to fatten up more to survive the winter.
Things weren't created for human convenience, with the exception of those whose breeding we have controlled. Even there, all we have been able to do until recently is recognize when desirable characteristics have arisen and encourage their propagation.
There is no indication that God, if she exists, has any opinion on our use or abuse of recreational chemicals, beyond their effects on our health and, if you want to stretch a point, their effects on our finances, which these days are also a factor in reproductive fitness. The religious will invoke free will on this topic, saying that God has left us free to choose our own risks and benefits. Some cultures will declare some or all kinds of intoxication to be sins, although many such only condemn overuse, or forbid one kind while allowing others. (I cannot speak with authority, but my understanding is that Islam forbids alcohol but permits some others.) Hence  I don't believe that a philosophical answer which crosses all cultures is possible.
Is it a gift? Is it a temptation? Is it just something that happens? Pick any or all of the above.
